# Move smalldatetime from databound DGV to new form textbox and change format

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, smalldatetime, newforms

I am currently working in windows form application in visual studio express for desktop. I also have an sql back end. I am trying to pull a smalldatetime from a DGV that has been loaded from an SQL table and then move it into a textbox on a new form. Right now the date format is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. I need the datetime to be in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Here is my code:-

Try

```
      Dim f As New frmCuttingMachineCutList

      If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        Dim Row_Index As Integer = DGVFinish.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        MsgBox(DGVFinish.Rows(Row_Index).Cells(5).Value)
        f.txtshear.Text = DGVFinish.Rows(Row_Index).Cells(5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        f.lblshear.Text = DGVFinish.Rows(Row_Index).Cells(1).Value

        End If


        f.Show()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I am getting an error that reads conversion from string "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to type integer is not valid -----> system.formatexception:Input String was not in a correct format. I dont see why it is trying to reformat the string into an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to convert your cell's value to a `DateTime` before being able to format it. Try

```
Dim date as DateTime = DGVFinish.Rows(Row_Index).Cells(5).Value as DateTime;
f.txtshear.Text = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: @Cheddar Glad to have helped :)